# Why rollback updated data automatically in Aliyun database?

Tags: sql, alibaba-cloud

When I updated the database using update query and after 30 minutes or 1 hour, rollback all updated data by the database automatically. I have checked db log. It contains the database did the rollback it self. Any idea what's the reason of this?

Comment: What's Aliyun??

Comment: It is a service provider in Alibaba cloud

Comment: Proper tags will give better attention.

Comment: Where did you run the update? How did you make sure the update succeed? Probably you didn't commit the transaction? If you have the log, paste the log here might help others help you.

Comment: Which Alibaba cloud database you are using and what are all the statements you have executed and rolled back. Were there any commit statement before the roll back. Please provide more detail.